# Paho subscriber on_message/on_connect not working

Tags: python, mqtt, mosquitto, paho

I've installed Mosquitto and used in the terminal without problem, also installed paho for c++, both mosquitto and paho work well. 
Then installed paho for python via pip. Now i'm trying to test it with this code but the on_message and on_connect functions never get called. I'm doing

`mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "test" -m "This is a message"`

while the python script runs but it doesn't work. It never gets to the line that prints "on_message!"

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(self, mqtt_client, obj, flags, rc):
    mqtt_client.subscribe("test")

def on_message(self, mqtt_client, obj, msg):
    print "on_message()"


print "Initializing subscriber"
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
mqtt_client.connect("localhost",1883)
print "Listening"
while True: 
    mqtt_client.loop()
```

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

The `on_message` callback gets called only if You are **subscribed** to a topic.
To do that, You need to call the [subscribe](https://pypi.org/project/paho-mqtt/#subscribe) method. For example:

```
print "Initializing subscriber"
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
mqtt_client.connect("localhost", 1883) # "localhost" or IP or 
mqtt_client.subscribe("test") # topic name, same as the "-t" argument in mosquitto_pub
print "Listening"
mqtt_client.loop_forever()
```

As for the `on_connect` callback, what caused the issue for me was that I called the [`connack_string`](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L194) method as it was `Client`'s method, but it is not. Looking at the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.python/blob/master/src/paho/mqtt/client.py#L194), we see that it is defined directly in the module, **not** inside a class:

```
def connack_string(connack_code):
```

So, I replaced this:

```
def connect_callback(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connection attempt returned: " + client.connack_string(rc)) # client !!
```

with this:

```
def connect_callback(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connection attempt returned: " + mqtt.connack_string(rc)) # mqtt !!
```

What You can also try is to omit the `-h localhost` part from the `mosquitto_pub` command, like this:

```
mosquitto_pub -t "test" -m "This is a message"
```

Also, watch for the number of parameters that the `on_connect` callback receives (**4**). This is advice to everybody else reading this post. :)

Comment: indeed, It did not call my on_connect callback because it was lacking 1 argument. It did not work on the new installation, though it had been working for 2 years with the previous installation !

Comment: I am glad I helped :) Thanks for commenting!

Answer (score 1):

The following is working fine for me.

I have removed the `self` from the callbacks and swapped the loop for `mqtt_client.loop_forever()`

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

def on_connect(mqtt_client, obj, flags, rc):
    mqtt_client.subscribe("test")

def on_message(mqtt_client, obj, msg):
    print "on_message()"


print "Initializing subscriber"
mqtt_client = mqtt.Client()
mqtt_client.on_connect = on_connect
mqtt_client.on_message = on_message
mqtt_client.connect("localhost",1883)
print "Listening"
mqtt_client.loop_forever()
```

Comment: Are you using mosquitto_pub -h localhost -t "test" -m "This is a message"?  

Because it still doesn't work for me. Maybe it's something from my system.

Comment: `mosquitto_pub -t test -m foo` but it's close enough (the default broker is localhost and no need for the quotes for single word messages)

Comment: Ok! Still not working, even with "mosquitto_pub -t test -m foo". Seems to be something from my system then. Thank you!

Comment: for me, it is working with `self` callbacks. however my problem was that i have not called any of the `loop*` functions. edit: i was wrong, it is working for me with `self` for the `connect` method, but for the `on_message` method the version with `self` is not working.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I just hit a similar problem. I had:

```
def on_message (client, userdata,message):
      print("received message", str(message.payload.decode("utf-8")

client.loop_start()
client.subscribe(topic)
client.on_message=on_message
time.sleep(30)
client.loop_stop()
```

If I changed the time from 30 to 300 then on_message was never executed.
Go figure?